# Checkin changes to another branch then we're currently working on

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

We've checked out and edited a lot of files on the main branch (new data framework).

Now we decided we need a feature branch because it will take more time than planned to finish this task.

Can we checkin the edits into a new branch?

It's ok if it needs an already created new branch, it's ok too if it creates a branch itself.

I've looked and looked and looked, but I can't find it, but I can't believe it doesn't exist, hence my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible by default using Visual Studio, but when you shelve your changes into a shelveset you can move that one to the other branche by using the TFS power tools.

The command you need is:

*tfpt unshelve shelvsetName /migrate /source:$/SourceBranch /target:$/TargetBranch*

You can find the TFS Power tools as package in the Extensions and updates section of Visual Studio.